# Crypto RSASSA-PSS algo in node.js

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptojs

I am using crypto. I have public key, data and signature. All working fine with openssl command

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -verify pk.pem -signature sigval1.sig data1.txt
```

But while using node crypto verify it always returning false

```js
crypto.verify(
    'RSA-SHA256',
    Buffer.from(data),
    newPublicKey,
    Buffer.from(signature, 'binary'),
  )
```

Requirement:
`"alg": "RSASSA-PSS","hash": "SHA256"`

Answer (score 1):

In the OpenSSL statement, PSS is used as padding. NodeJS applies PKCS#1 v1.5 padding by default, so PSS must be explicitly specified in the third parameter in [`crypto.verify(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptoverifyalgorithm-data-key-signature-callback):

```js
var verified = crypto.verify(
    'RSA-SHA256',
    Buffer.from(data, 'utf-8'),
    {
        key: newPublicKey, 
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING,
        //saltLength: crypto.constants.RSA_PSS_SALTLEN_MAX_SIGN // default
    },
    Buffer.from(signature, 'binary')
);
```

Note that the OpenSSL statement uses the *maximum* possible salt length as the salt length, rather than the default given in [RFC8017](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.2.3), which is the output length of the digest. This is not critical here in that `crypto.verify()` also uses the maximum salt length (`crypto.constants.RSA_PSS_SALTLEN_MAX_SIGN`).